# Pandas Dataframes - Populating df2 based on criteria in df1

Tags: python, pandas

I've got this dataframe (df1) based on which I want to input data into another dataframe (df2). If the value of df1 is > than 54 I want the same row in df2 to be "Buy" under the "Buy " column and if its not I want it to be "Sell" under the "sell" column. I know this sounds easy but for some reason when I was doing this with the code below it was setting all the values in df2 based on the last value in df1.

```
for x in df1['A']:
    if x > 54:
       df2['Buy'] = "Buy"

    else:
       df2['Sell'] = "Sell"
```

df1:

```
    Date
    2011-08-26     53.024284
    2011-08-29     55.454285
    2011-08-30     55.464287
    2011-08-31     55.795715
    2011-09-01     55.117142
    2011-09-02     53.534286

df2:

            Buy  Hold  Sell
Date
2011-08-26  0.0    0.0   0.0
2011-08-29  0.0    0.0   0.0
2011-08-30  0.0    0.0   0.0
2011-08-31  0.0    0.0   0.0
2011-09-01  0.0    0.0   0.0
2011-09-02  0.0    0.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 4):

First is necessarry both index are same and then is possible use boolean mask created by condition in `df1` in another DataFrame `df2`:

```
m = df1['A'] > 54
df2['Buy'] = df2['Buy'].mask(m, "Buy")
df2['Sell'] = df2['Sell'].mask(~m, "Sell")
```

Same as [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df2 = df2.assign(Buy= df2['Buy'].mask(m, "Buy"),Sell = df2['Sell'].mask(~m, "Sell"))
```

Or:

```
df2.loc[m, 'Buy'] = "Buy"
df2.loc[~m, 'Sell'] = "Sell"
```

---

```
print (df2)
            Buy  Hold  Sell
Date                       
2011-08-26    0   0.0  Sell
2011-08-29  Buy   0.0     0
2011-08-30  Buy   0.0     0
2011-08-31  Buy   0.0     0
2011-09-01  Buy   0.0     0
2011-09-02    0   0.0  Sell
```

If indexes are different use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
m = (df1['A'] > 54).reindex(df2.index, fill_value=False)
```

Comment: Sir you got me by reindexing. Will remember this one. Im seeing reindexing on mask for first time : )

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where` i.e

```
df2['Buy'] = np.where(df1['A']>54,'Buy',df2['Buy'])
df2['Sell'] = np.where(df1['A']<54,'Sell',df2['Sell'])
```

or `df.where` i.e

```
df2['Buy'] = df2['Buy'].where(df1['A']<54,'Buy')
df2['Sell'] = df2['Sell'].where(df1['A']>54,'Sell')
```

Output :

```
            Buy  Hold  Sell
Date                       
2011-08-26  0.0   0.0  Sell
2011-08-29  Buy   0.0   0.0
2011-08-30  Buy   0.0   0.0
2011-08-31  Buy   0.0   0.0
2011-09-01  Buy   0.0   0.0
2011-09-02  0.0   0.0  Sell
```

If the indices are not same then you have to go for reindexing as suggested by @jezrael in his solution.